# Script is getting hanged and not giving any output

Tags: java, multithreading, shell

I have return one script which on execution modifies a line in one file.

Flow for working script is from run method after printing checkpoint 111 it is going to executeCmd method after printing checkpoint aaaa, execution again goes to run method prints checkpoint 222 and comeback to executeCmd method and exit the execution after printing bbb.

But in my case after checkpoint aaa it is printing checkpoint bbb and this loop is never ending so execution is not going back to run method and hence script is stuck and hangs the session.

```
public String executeCmd(String classOpts, String cmdLine, String[] opts)
{   
    while (myCmd.isAlive() == true)
    {   
        try
        {
            log.debug("checkpoint aaaa");
            Thread.sleep(100);
            log.debug("checkpoint bbbb");
        }
    }
    exitVal = myCmd.getCmdExitValue();
    log.debug("The script exit code: = " + exitVal);
}

public void run()
{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try
    {
        String sCommand = cmdUtils.sScriptLauncher + " " + this.cmdline;
        proc = rt.exec(cmdUtils.sScriptLauncher + " " + this.cmdline;
        proc = rt.exec(cmdUtils.ParseCommandLine(sCommand));            
        try
        {
            log.debug("Checkpoint 111");    
            cmdExitVal = proc.waitFor();`enter code here`
            log.debug("Checkpoint 222");    
        } 
//remaining code
```

Comment: Please help me to resolve this
I have already spent 2 whole days trying different scenarios and none is wroking, i suspect problem either in wait for method or in Thread.sleep

Comment: this code doesn't compile does it?

Comment: 1. Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`; 2. you don't do anything with the script's stdout and stderr: if the script outputs anything, it will block.

Answer (score 0):

I use following class `RunProcessCMD` that uses `ProcessBuilder`, `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
class RunProcessCMD {  


    static BufferedReader stdout, stderr;
    private Boolean isWaitFor = true;// wait for reply from CMD

    private static RunProcessCMD startRunProcessCMD = null;

    private String[] input = null;
    private static boolean isRealTime = false;

    private static StringBuilder buff = null;

    public static RunProcessCMD getInstance(){
        if(startRunProcessCMD == null){
            startRunProcessCMD = new RunProcessCMD();
        }

        return startRunProcessCMD;
    }

    private RunProcessCMD(){}// destroy public constructor 

    public void start(String[] command) throws IOException {
        buff = new StringBuilder();


         System.out.println(Arrays.asList( command ) );

        ProcessBuilder launcher = new ProcessBuilder();
        launcher.redirectErrorStream(true);


        launcher.command(command);

        launcher.start(); // And launch a new process


        buff.append("Done").append("\n");System.out.println("Done.");


    }

    public void start () throws IOException, InterruptedException{

          buff = new StringBuilder();

                    if(input == null){
                     buff.append("Command == null");

                     return;            
                    }

           //String[] input = new String[] {"tasklist"};

           Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

           //System.out.println("Execute ...");

           //Process p = r.exec("cmd /c", input, null);
           System.out.println(Arrays.asList( input ) );
           Process p = r.exec(input);


           //System.out.println("Finish to execute, start read output");

           InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
           stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
           is = p.getErrorStream();
           stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

           //outputLines = new Vector();

           if( isWaitFor == true ){
            StdoutThread cltOut = RunProcessCMD.getInstance().new StdoutThread();   
            Thread tOut = new Thread(cltOut);
            tOut.start();

            StderrThread cltErr = RunProcessCMD.getInstance().new StderrThread();   
            Thread tErr = new Thread(cltErr);
            tErr.start();

            p.waitFor();
           }



           buff.append("Done").append("\n");System.out.println("Done.");

           if( isWaitFor == false ){
            buff.append("WaitFor defined to be false, respectivally no output from CMD").append("\n");
            System.out.println("WaitFor defined to be false, respectively no output from CMD");
           }

         }

    private  class StdoutThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int l;
                String line;

                for(l = 0; (line = stdout.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    if (line.length() > 0) 
                        l++;
                        //outputLines.addElement(line);
                        buff.append(line).append("\n");

                    if(!line.trim().equals("")){
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                }
                stdout.close();
            } 
            catch(IOException ie) { 
                buff.append("IO exception on stdout: " + ie).append("\n");
            }
        }
    }


    private  class StderrThread implements Runnable {

        public StderrThread() {}

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int l;
                String line;
                for(l = 0; (line = stderr.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    if (line.length() > 0) l++;
                    buff.append(line).append("\n");                                     
                        System.out.print(line);

                }
                stderr.close();
            } 
            catch(IOException ie) { 
                buff.append("IO exception on stdout: " + ie).append("\n");//System.out.println("IO exception on stdout: " + ie);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void ClearBuff (){
        buff.setLength(0);
        isRealTime = false;
    }

    public void setInput(String[] input) {
        // reset flag
        isWaitFor = true;

        if(input[input.length-1].contains("waitFor") && input[input.length-1].split("=").length == 2 ){

            String bull = input[input.length-1].split("=")[1];

            isWaitFor = new Boolean( bull ); 

            System.out.println("isWaitFor = " + isWaitFor);

            // remove last value from String array
            String[] input_new = new String[input.length -1];

            for(int k=0; k < input_new.length; k++){
                input_new[k] = input[k];
            }

            input = input_new;

        }

        // add proper value for input       
        String[] str = new String[input.length + 2];
        str[0] = "cmd.exe";
        str[1] = "/c";

        for(int i=2; i<str.length; i++){
            str[i] = input[i-2];
        }

        this.input = str;
    }

    public static StringBuilder getBuff() {

        if( buff == null ){
          return new StringBuilder( "" );
        }

        return buff;
    }

    public void setRealTime(boolean b) {
        isRealTime  = b;
    }   

}
```

**Usage:**

```
private void runSomeCommandOverCmd(){


    String runP = "adb devices";


    String[] strArr = new String[2];
    strArr[0] = runP;
    strArr[1] = "waitFor=true";

    RunProcessCMD.getInstance().setInput( strArr );

    try {
        RunProcessCMD.getInstance().start();

        String str = ( RunProcessCMD.getBuff() ).toString();

        System.out.println(str);

        RunProcessCMD.ClearBuff();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            throw new Exception( "Failed to Start process CMD" );
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }           

}
```